Let say we have two different fluids, what are the main properties they have that is needed in order to determine convection constant h
I have searched a lot on the thermal interaction by convection between two different fluids having different properties, but did not find anything useful, all of results were talking about only convection between a fluid, and a solid surface which is not what I am looking for. What I am looking forward is the convection between two different fluids moving relative to each other

Are the fluids miscible?

No, they are separated by a thin layer and cannot combine

you have to solve the differential heat balance and flow equations to obtain this.
